# create an instance of DataSource and use inside constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

In my current spring-boot project, I have this class:

```
@Component
public class OauthTokenStore extends JdbcTokenStore {
  public OauthTokenStore() {
    super(...);
  }
}
```

the atribute for `super(...)` should be a valid datasource. I have this configuration in my `application.properties`:

```
# jdbc.X
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lojacms
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

# hibernate.X
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Is there any way to create an instance of a datasource and use in this constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject a `DataSource` bean which you can then pass it to your `OauthTokenStore` constructor using `@Inject`.

```
@Component
public class OauthTokenStore extends JdbcTokenStore {

  @Inject
  public OauthTokenStore(DataSource ds) {
    super(ds);
  }
}
```

If you don't yet have a bean of type `DataSource` defined in your application you'll need one:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lojacms");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```